# Determine if $(2,0,1,0)$ is a base of $F$, a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $\dim F = 2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

My book's solutions say it isn't but I don't understand why not. This vector can be written as a linear combination of 2 vectors:
$$(2,0,1,0) = 2(1,0,0,0)+1(0,0,1,0) \\
F = \langle (1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\rangle$$

Both of these vectors are linearly independent, and there's two vectors ($\dim F = 2$). Why isn't $(2,0,1,0)$ a base of F?

Comment: how would you express $(1,0,0,0)\in F$ as a linear combination of $(2,0,1,0)$?  (any element of $F$ should be expressible as a linear combination of basis vectors)

Comment: $\dim F=2$ means you need *two* vectors in a basis for $F$

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Did you have any questions about the solution I posted? Let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard No questions, thanks

Comment: You’ve gotten it backwards. The goal isn’t to write this one vector as a linear combination of two other vectors that probably have nothing to do with $F$ whatsoever. I highly recommend you review the definition of the dimension of a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a basis is not a vector. A basis is a set of vectors. So $(2,0,1,0)$ can't be a basis because it's just a vector. It's not a set of vectors.

Second, if a vector space $V$ has dimension $n$, then any basis for $V$ must have $n$ elements.

We're given that $F$ is the space spanned by $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,0)$. Hence $F$ has dimension $2$. Hence any basis for $F$ must be a set of two vectors.

$(2,0,1,0)$ is just one vector. We would need a set of two vectors to get a basis for $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not.  A single vector spans at most a one dimensional space.  But $F$ is two dimensional (span of two linearly independent vectors).